# sms_autofill Unable to detect the OTP

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used the **sms_autofill** plugin to to auto-detect the OTP received on mobile and type it in the given **PinFieldAutoFill**, As per https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill#-readme-tab- I am using `await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode;` function before making my API request & when the request has got a 200 status code I'm navigating it to another page and in `init` I'm listening to the OTP SMS received by using `await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode;` I thought like maybe when the page is initialized it wont be listening again to any SMS so i did add a **Timer** also but still it was not receiving anything.

**Dependency** - `sms_autofill: ^1.2.6`

Code : Page1

```
Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Register'),
          onPressed: () async {
            await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode;
            final signCode = await SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature;
            print(signCode);
            //Http request code
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Code : Page2

```
String appSignature;
  String otpCode;
  Timer timer;

  @override
  void codeUpdated() {
    setState(() {
      otpCode = code;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listenOTP();
//    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t){
//      print('OTP Listening');
//      listenOTP();
//    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Code Received: $otpCode",
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                codeLength: 6,
                onCodeChanged: (val) {
                  print(val);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void listenOTP() async {
    print('listen for code');
    await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sms format is not right. The sms format should be like:

> ExampleApp: Your code is 123456
> FA+9qCX9VSu //this is your app signature

if your message is different. You can follow this answer to handle any type of sms format otp https://stackoverflow.com/a/70076071/6067774