# How do I properly listen for sms code flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used [PinPut](https://pub.dev/packages/pinput) package for my flutter app for users to validate their phone's code after I send it from my custom backend. Everything works perfectly, but I wanted an auto-fill mechanism such that they don't have to place it manually everytime. So,i tried switching to [Sms Autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill) package but I didn't like the way its input field looks as I wanted more customisations. (The auto-fill didn't work for me anyways).

Now, am using [SMS receiver](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_retriever_api/example) package alongside my preferred **PinPut** widget. The idea is that I want to listen for the sms code and pass it to my PinPut's controller. But sadly, the listener don't work as I don't get the messages with my code implementation.

**This is my code:**

```
 String _smsCode = "";
  bool isListening = false;

  getCode(String sms) {
    print("Snskndksdnn");
    if (sms != null) {
      final intRegex = RegExp(r'\d+', multiLine: true);
      final code = intRegex.allMatches(sms).first.group(0);

      return code;
    }
    return "NO SMS";
  }

  Future<void> onSubmitPhone() async {
    ///close keyboard
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    errorPhone = _cv.contentValidator(
        phone.text.toString().trim(), '[0-9]{10,11}', errorPhone);
   
      if(errorPhone == null){
        var _api = SmsRetrieverApi();
        setState(() {});
        await _api.startListening(onReceived: (smsCode){
          _smsCode = getCode(smsCode);
          isListening = false;
        
        });
      
        Map<String, String> data = new Map();
        data = {
          "phoneNumber": phoneUpdate
        };
        try{
          Map<String, dynamic> _res = await authenticationService.sendOTP(data);
          if(_res['success'] ==true){
            AlertManager.showToast(_res['data']['smsStatus']);
            setState(() {
              isSendIngOTP = false;
              pinId = '${_res['data']['pinId']}';
            });
            _pageController.nextPage(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.ease,
            );
         
        }

      }
    } 
  }
```

Any ideas to get my desired result?

Comment: It might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65559187/how-to-get-otp-from-sms-autofill

Comment: both solutions don't work for me

Comment: check this package's documentation it should help - https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill

Comment: @theiskaa I don't fancy their custom input field