# flutter how to get OTP autofill in to otpController.text from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

**flutter how to get OTP autofill into otpController.text from firebase**
--: when get OTP in mobile, need to auto-fills OTP in a text box, i am doing it in _onVerificationCompleted method.

```
_onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential authCredential) async {

debugPrint("verification completed ${authCredential.smsCode}");
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
setState(() {
    // need otp so i can autofill in a textbox
otpController.text = authCredential.smsCode!;
});
if (authCredential.smsCode != null) {
try {
    UserCredential credential =
    await user!.linkWithCredential(authCredential);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'provider-already-linked') {
    await auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
    }
}

}
}
Future<void> sendOtp() async {

print(numController.text);
await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(

phoneNumber: "+91" + numController.text,

verificationCompleted: _onVerificationCompleted,

verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
    if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
    print('The provided phone number is not valid.');
    }
},

codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
    this.verificationId = verificationId;
    signature = await SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature;
    print("app signature");
    print(signature);
    setState(() {
    visibleValMobile = false;
    visibleValOtp = true;
    sendOtpMobile = "We Have Send OTP On " + numController.text;
    });

},

codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
    print('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout');
},
);
}
```

flutter when get OTP in mobile, it auto-fills a text box

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of options like [otp_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/otp_autofill), [alt_sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/alt_sms_autofill) and [sms_autofill](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill)

For the alt_sms_autofill example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/70076071/4639894

Comment: Need device permission for alt_sms_autofill ?

Comment: it may need permission to read sms

Comment: thank you suzan, alt_sms_autofill its working, but one problem is there. when i click resend OTP -> then 2nd time OTP not autofill. only autofill work for 1st time. so please tell me what should i do.